# Merge two Paragraph objects

Tags: java, itext

I want to insert a piece of text in a PDF which contains bold and not-bold areas, but I do not know how can I do this ?

I'm using iText5 (java).

This is my code:

```
public class CreatePdf{
   private Font bigFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, "Windows-1254", 12, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0));
   private Font smallFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, "Windows-1254", 8, Font.NORMAL, new Color(0, 0, 0));

   public void create(){
      Paragraph parag1=new Paragraph("Number: ",bigFont);//This gonna be bold font
      Paragraph parag2=new Paragraph("12", smallFont); //This gonna be normal font

      //Create one paragraph from these two paragraphs. But How ?
   }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution: `Paragraph comb=new Paragraph(); comb.add(new Chunk(parag1)) com.add(new Chunk(parag2))`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
public class CreatePdf{
   private Font bigFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, "Windows-1254", 12, Font.BOLD, new Color(0, 0, 0));
   private Font smallFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, "Windows-1254", 8, Font.NORMAL, new Color(0, 0, 0));

   public void create(){
      Paragraph parag1=new Paragraph("Number: ",bigFont);//This gonna be bold font
      Paragraph parag2=new Paragraph("12", smallFont); //This gonna be normal font
      Paragraph comb=new Paragraph(); 
      comb.add(new Chunk(parag1)) 
      comb.add(new Chunk(parag2)); 
   }
}
```

Comment: accept it! btw you write simply `comb.add(new Chunk(text, font));`

Answer (score 7):

You can make simpler:

```
comb.add(parag1);
comb.add(parag2);
```

The Chunk is not necessary.

Comment: in later versions of 5, this is the only valid method, as you can no longer create a Chunk from a Paragraph or a Phrase

Answer (score 0):

```
        Chunk parag1 = new Chunk("Number: ", texto);//This gonna be bold font
        Chunk parag2 = new Chunk("12", textosub); //This gonna be normal font
        Paragraph comb = new Paragraph();
        comb.Add(new Chunk(parag1));
        comb.Add(new Chunk(parag2));
        pdfDoc.Add(comb);
```